# Create own webmap

Tags: javascript, gis

I'm looking for tools to create own, drawed map, which will behaves as normal map, something like this: http://viewers-guide.hbo.com/game-of-thrones/season-4/episode-10/map/location/8/castle-black

What would you recommend?

Comment: I would create the map in SVG, then I would make my thing with javascript, and then I would integrate it with my wiki.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially, your question text should be self-contained – references are fine, but please don't expect potential answerers to investigate another website to guess what you might need ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd draw it in QGIS (Free Desktop software) and publish using the QGIS2Web application to get something nice looking to show on a website.

Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCnNWyl9qSE to give you a taste of QGIS

I recreated the London Tube map using QGIS and it was a great learning experience (but I already do GIS for a living)